# Eliminating a cartridge fuse subpanel

Tags: subpanel

The house was built in 1957 and the electrical has been updated over the years. Recently I expanded the 2nd floor and have a new main service in the garage.

Under the basement steps is a cartridge fuse subpanel with 4 circuits being fed from main panel in the basement which is now a subpanel being fed from the new service in the garage. I'd like to eliminate the cartridge fuse subpanel and run new wire from garage to each circuit eliminating the need for a subpanel.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: can you post photos of the main panel and the existing subpanel please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're up for running new wire, you can either run new wire to the fuse panel, remove the guts, and use it as a junction box (assuming, as is likely, it's large enough for wire fill), or you can run new wire to the general area and install new junction boxes as needed to connect each new cable/wires to each circuit currently served by the fuse panel.

Depending on access and what you want to do, you could also run the new wire to the first device on each circuit, with no extra junction box needed.